# Firebase dynamic links don't work on galaxy s8 and galaxy s9

Tags: android, firebase, dynamic-links

I have a problem on galaxy s8 and galaxy s9 with dynamic links from firebase. On other android devices it works. A strange loading screen appears, then returns to the application from which there was an attempt to open the application. Anyone had a similar problem or potentially knows a solution? The application is not installed. Certificate SHA-1 is attached. https://drive.google.com/open?id=15BTDWjFgMtijZ7RVILN7DUq-fG0BzlE7

Answer (score 0):

on the next day the links started to work correctly ... it looked like a problem with permissions on devices